# Threading behaviour of SignalR

Tags: multithreading, signalr

I have a SignalR Hub on my ASP.NET server and I have a listening signalR client in my JavaScript page.

When I push a message from my server hub to my client does the code wait until all bytes have been sent before proceeding or does it internally spawn it off in a separate thread?

For instance, consider this server code (c#).

```
foreach (string hubUserId in hubUserIds)
{
    context.Clients.Client(hubUserId).broadcastMessage('this could be a large byte array');
}
```

I am not experiencing any delays sending messages at the moment and by observations it does not seem to wait until data has been pushed out. But I could be wrong.

If it does not spawn a thread can I safely do so myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking a method on a client returns an awaitable task.

In your example, you are not awaiting it - so the invocation will be asynchronous and will happen in the background.

The official documentation where this is outlined is at:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#asyncclient

You can read more about async/await in ASP.Net at:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4